# Is it possible to tame a villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been watching TDM videos and I noticed his villager friend in the lab, Dr. Trayaurus, always follows him. I also noticed it teleports. This made me want to build my own AWESOME lab. I wanted my own villager too. I named it Dr. Trayaurus when it was a baby and waited the 20 mins, but I don't know if I can tame it. Can I tame it without a mod? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Not in Vanilla Minecraft.

There are two possibilities:

1. **Modded Villager AI** (less likely)**:**

TDM has a modded Villager AI. Basically, this just means he has a Villager that is "tweaked" to follow him. There are probably a few mods that will do this for you. I'm sure a quick google search can find a few.

2. **Vanilla Villager + Editing** (more likely)**:**

What seems to be much more likely is that his villagers are just plain Vanilla. They don't necessarily "follow him around" (any illusion is done through editing or the AI deciding to head towards TDM), nor teleport, nor make the noises at the perfect time. If TDM wants their faithful villager in a certain area at a certain scene, he probably just spawns in a white-robe villager and names it. Also, the teleportation might just be an artifact of a cut in the video or something. In the same way, the sounds perfectly on queue can easily be added in post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

In the Vanilla version, you cant tame Villagers.

## What I have researched about Dr.Trayaurus

- He is a Modded Villager
- He came from Custom NPC Mod
- If the option **Follow** is enabled, he will act like a tamed mobs
- The sound that he makes is edited trough video editing software

## What should you do if you want to create Dr.Trayaurus in your world

1. Install **Custom NPC** Mod for Minecraft (Any version)
2. Create a Villager NPC and name it **Dr.Trayaurus**
3. Done. Set **Following** to **true** so the mobs will follow you (Can teleport to you)

Answer (score -2):

you can hook the Villager up to a lead if you play in a version after 1.6.2, otherwise there would be no way to make it follow you and "tame" it.

Comment: And it's wrong ._.